# Design practicality of using a segmented control with a single option in the navigation bar

Tags: ios, user-interface

I am nearing completion of my first app that will be submitted to the app store and I just wanted to make sure I am not committing high treason against the iOS Human Interface Guidelines. I have added a segmented control with a single option: Sort List. It essentially functions as a UIButton since I set its selectedSegmentIndex to -1 after a sort option has been chosen. I set it up this way due to difficulties with adding a button to the navigation item's titleView. Additionally, a "Search" option may be added in an update in the near future and having the segmented control there will make it easier to add. I have done some preliminary testing with the clients and other volunteers, and everybody approves.

**My question is "Will Apple approve the app if it has this segmented control posing as a button? And is it an acceptable design in general?"**

I have read the guidelines and other documentation and I can't seem to find anything saying I shouldn't do this but I would like hear your thoughts regarding this and/or any experiences you have had with something similar.

Here are some screenshots to give you a better idea:

[image]

Comment: You could always use the segmented control the way that it is intended and have two segments which bypasses the need for the separate view and everything.  This will also be familiar to iOS users and will do what they expect of a segmented control which is what is suggested in the guidelines for changing how you look at a view.

Comment: Yes, you have a point. I have used the segmented control in the manner you speak of before but the sort options are too large to fit within the segmented control this time. Sorting options across all tabs includes Category Name, Release Date, Presenter Name, and Media Title. It looked much too packed in when trying to fit these option in the segments.

Comment: Ann, your example only showed two choices so I thought it would work better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no, you probably won’t get rejected from the App Store for using a segmented control this way.

Longer answer: What you should probably be doing instead is placing the “Sort” control as a bar button item in the left of the navigation bar (or on the right, moving the “refresh” control to the left, if you intend to push more things onto the navigation stack). It would also be better to use an action sheet (UIActionSheet) for your sorting options, rather than a page-curled additional view controller.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion with the UIActionSheet. I believe I will do that. I have the sort option in the center because the back button on the left and the refresh on the right as more is pushed onto the navigation stack.